# Magento 1.9 - Mage::log() isn't creating the log files

Tags: magento

Before you mark this as duplicate... hold off, because nothing from the other questions is working so far.

So like it says, `Mage::log()` doesn't seem to be working. I'm guessing it's a permissions issue, but yet I can't solve it for the life of me. I've been following along with a [tutorial](https://magenticians.com/create-magento-custom-module/) on making an extension and all was going well until this log thing. I see the module in the magento admin panel and I know it runs when it's supposed to because if I syntactically break the `Observer.php` file, the website breaks. Interestingly, when I did THAT, it did make a `system.log` file, but googling tells me that this might just mean a cron job that does have write permission wrote to the file, but magento still cannot.

**Things I have tried already:**

- Cache is disabled in magento, and cleared
- Logging is enabled. I also enabled debugging, fwiw, but I don't really know what it does.
- Initially the line was `Mage::log("{$name} ({$sku}) updated", null, 'product-updates.log');`. This didn't create any log file though. I changed it to `Mage::log("{$name} ({$sku}) updated", null, 'product-updates.log', true);` which the `true` supposedly means do it whether logging is enabled or not. No change. Also tried just simple `Mage::log("My log entry");` at the beginning and end of file. Nothing.
- In terms of permissions, I don't understand it all enough to be making up my own commands to try, but I've tried basically every option I've found on the internet, and nothing has solved this. (I'm using an ubuntu server) The current config from the base magento path that I've tried is:

  ```
  sudo usermod -a -G www-data <myUser>
  sudo chown -R :www-data .
  find . -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
  find . -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \; 
  find var/ -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; 
  find media/ -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
  find var/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; 
  find media/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
  chmod 770 includes
  chmod 660 includes/config.php
  chmod -R 777 var/
  ```

  On FileZilla I can confirm that the log folder has permissions `drwxrwxrwx` and the `system.log` file inside has `-rwxrwxrwx` so why won't it write to the log file?? If there's any other useful info that I didn't include, just let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I did... I wanna say it ended up being a case where this wasn't the actual problem. I think it was that my php was silently failing on another issue, and thus wasn't getting to the log line. I was still figuring out how php worked. Pretty sure once I resolved that, it started logging.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. In the end it was due to a recent patch - see https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269187/46258

Answer (score 0):

Check if your logs are enabled under System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I meant when I said logs were enabled. And even if they somehow weren't, that fourth argument "true" should cause it to log either way.